# How to make sql return values even if it doesn't exist in a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So I got a table called pet_size which represents... pet sizes!
The sizes can be:

```
id name  
1  small  
2  medium  
3  large
```

Also, there's 0 which represents unknown or not provided, but it is not added to the table.

Then I got this query:

```
SELECT pet_breed.id, pet_breed.breed_name, pet_type.type_name, pet_size.size_name
FROM pet_breed,
     pet_type,
     pet_size
WHERE pet_breed.petTypeId = pet_type.id
  AND pet_breed.sizeId = pet_size.id
ORDER BY pet_breed.id
```

The above works perfectly for any record except these who got 0 in the pet_breed.sizeId, since it doesn't exist in pet_size.id, what's the most elegant way to fix it, besides of adding a dummy value to pet_size table?

I want that if the sizeId is 0, just use "unknown" as the size_name.

And finally if the above query can be optimized in any way?

Comment: Tag only the dbms used! Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: The best option, and definitely the simplest one, would be to add a record with `0, 'unknown'` values into pet sizes table.

Comment: Step 1) switch to modern, explicit `join` syntax. Step 2) convert to `left join`.

Comment: "0 which represents unknown or not provided". You should be using `NULL` here.

Comment: Side note - read [Aaron Bertrand's Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Updated the tag thanks @jarlh using mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the old style joins, update to use correct `LEFT JOIN` and you'll get the result you're expecting

```
SELECT 
pb.id
,pb.breed_name
,pt.type_name
,IFNULL(ps.size_name,'Unknown') size_name
FROM pet_breed pb
LEFT JOIN pet_type pt
    ON pb.petTypeId = pt.id 
LEFT JOIN pet_size ps
    ON pb.sizeId = ps.id
ORDER BY pb.id
```

I've updated this with table aliases which will make your code more readable too.

Your old joins were acting as `INNER JOINS` which will only return rows with matching values in all tables.

Edit: Re-read the question and put an `ISNULL` in to catch where data doesn't match.

Edit2: IFNULL for mysql, not ISNULL

Comment: Thank, just a heads-up I had to change ISNULL to IFNULL for mysql.

Comment: Nice one. Wasn't sure which system you were using at the time with the tags.